# VBA VLookUp not working

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

Hi I am trying to use the VLookUp function in VBA.
It comes with the error, " Unable to get the VLookUp property of the worksheetFunction class"
It is trying to take data from a sheet called 13.09.2017

```
Sub VLookUp()

Dim i As Integer

Dim k As Integer

For i = 1 To 10

 ThisWorksheet.Cells(1 + i, 11) = WorksheetFunction.VLookUp(Cells(1 + i, 2), Worksheets("13.09.2017").Range("B2:K11"), 10, False)

Next

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKhJR.png)
I hope you can help me

Comment: there is no `ThisWorksheet` in VBA

Answer (score 0):

`ThisWorksheet` is not part of the VBA object library. You probably need `ThisWorksbook`

This is how to do it, if you want to use the ActiveSheet(this is not adviseable, but it works):

```
Sub VLookUp()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To 10
            .Cells(1 + i, 11) = WorksheetFunction.VLookUp(.Cells(1 + i, 2), _
                 Worksheets("13.09.2017").Range("B2:K11"), 10, False)
        Next
    End with

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside `ThisWorksheet` issue, your code will break on first instance where vlookup doesn't find value in range. If this is the only code you will be running, then add `On Error Resume Next` statement to avoid error.

```
Sub VLookUp()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    With ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To 10
        .Cells(1 + i, 11) = WorksheetFunction.VLookUp(.Cells(1 + i, 2), _
            Worksheets("13.09.2017").Range("B2:K11"), 10, False)
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```