# I am using If condition in a manual format where I need a function for that

Tags: excel-formula

I have used the below code and still needs to add two more regions. But it is not allowing me.

MS EXCEL

> ```
>  =IF(AO2="China","GCNA",IF(AO2="Hong Kong","GCNA",IF(AO2="Japan","GCNA",IF(AO2="Korea","GCNA",IF(AO2="Macau","GCNA",IF(AO2="Taiwan","GCNA",IF(AO2="Australia","ASA",IF(AO2="Bangladesh","ASA",IF(AO2="Brunei","ASA",IF(AO2="Cambodia","ASA",IF(AO2="India","ASA",IF(AO2="Indonesia","ASA",IF(AO2="Laos","ASA",IF(AO2="Malaysia","ASA",IF(AO2="Myanmar","ASA",IF(AO2="Nepal","ASA",IF(AO2="Philippines","ASA",IF(AO2="Angola","AME",IF(AO2="Bahrain","AME",IF(AO2="Botswana","AME",IF(AO2="Cameroon","AME",IF(AO2="Cote
>  D'lvorie","AME",IF(AO2="Egypt","AME",IF(AO2="Gambia","AME",IF(AO2="Ghana","AME",IF(AO2="Iraq","AME",IF(AO2="Jordan","AME",IF(AO2="Nigeria","AME",IF(AO2="Oman","AME",IF(AO2="Pakistan","AME",IF(AO2="Qatar","AME",IF(AO2="Saudi
>  Arabia","AME",IF(AO2="Sierra Leone","AME",IF(AO2="South
>  Africa","AME",IF(AO2="Tanzania","AME",IF(AO2="UAE","AME",IF(AO2="Uganda","AME",IF(AO2="Argentina","E&A",IF(AO2="Brazil","E&A",IF(AO2="Colombia","E&A",IF(AO2="Falkland
>  Island","E&A",IF(AO2="France","E&A",IF(AO2="Germany","E&A",IF(AO2="Ireland","E&A",IF(AO2="Jersey","E&A",IF(AO2="Poland","E&A",IF(AO2="Sweden","E&A",IF(AO2="Turkey","E&A",IF(AO2="UK","E&A",IF(AO2="US","E&A",IF(AO2="Brunei
>  Darussalam","ASA",IF(AO2="Cote
>  D'Ivoire","AME",IF(AO2="Guernsey","E&A",IF(AO2="IVORY
>  COAST","AME",IF(AO2="Kenya","AME",IF(AO2="Jersey
>  C.I.","E&A",IF(AO2="Zambia","AME",IF(AO2="Mauritius","ASA",IF(AO2="Srilanka","ASA",IF(AO2="Singapore","ASA",IF(AO2="Vietnam","ASA",IF(AO2="Thailand","ASA",IF(AO2="United
>  States","E&A",IF(AO2="United Kingdom","E&A",IF(AO2="United Arab
>  Emirates","AME","Error")))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
> ```

I need to add two more regions : Zimbabwe and
Korea Republic of

Comment: Welcome to SO. *But it is not allowing me* is unclear, could you be more specific? Also, if you explain what you are trying to do, maybe you can get help on that issue with a different approach. It looks like depending of the value of `AO2`, you want to return a specific value for each country. I **strongly** suggest you to check **[VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is an example of both vlookup and index with match:

[image]

I "cherry picked" countries just as an example, you can add all you need but do make sure you take the complete range in either vlookup or with index match.

Error trapping can be done as well:

```
IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2,A1:B5,2,0),"Not in List")
```

Comment: So if it answers your question please accept it with the check mark top left or at least vote for it.

Comment: Is it possible to automate VLOOKUP through VBA or Macro?

Comment: Yes, easily possible. A suitable starter exercise - consider using the record macro function and work from there.

Comment: @SoumitaBhattacharjee you should also look on here - there are several already... but building and understanding your own may be quicker or more useful than trying to edit a chunk of code to match your needs...

Comment: @SoumitaBhattacharjee have a look at this (but one of many you can find) as an example : https://stackoverflow.com/q/46406632/4961700